# Maven dependency Conflict - Trouble with understanding version managed from 2.6.0

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven dependency conflict.

It seems that I have jar conflicts and so I ran the following command -

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.x.b
```

Added the necessary exclusions and ran the command again to get the following output

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.2:tree (default-cli) @ domain-crypto ---
[INFO] com.x.platform.y.z:domain-crypto:jar:119.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.x.b:java-cryptoclient:jar:2.6.0:compile

[INFO] com.x.platform.y.z:domain-processorclient:jar:119.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.x.platform.y.z:domain-crypto:jar:119.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.x.b:java-cryptoclient:jar:1.1:compile (version managed from 2.6.0)
```

So from what I understand it should be 2.6.0 however what is causing me confusion is the "(version managed from 2.6.0)" part.

Does it mean that it is using 1.1 or does it mean its using 2.6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during compilation of x.platform.y.z:domain-crypto, 2.6.0 will be present and your source will be compiled against that

during compilation of x.platform.y.z:domain-processorclient, 1.1 will be present and your source will be compiled against that

At runtime it depends on how you configured your app (usually whichever comes first in dependencies list gets precedence)